# Trying to add versioning using filemtime but fail

Tags: php, wordpress, versioning, filemtime

On a wordpress environment.

I'm trying to automatically add versioning to my scripts using `filemtime`, but get the following error message:

```
Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for (file name)
```

the code is simple

```
$myfile = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js';
wp_enqueue_script('mywebsite-script',$myfile , array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( $myfile ), true );
```

the path to the file is correct, but as I said I get the `stat failed` message.

If I add the `if (file_exists($myfile))` check, the whole operation is skipped.
Yet if I echo the path to `$myfile`, this is correctly printed and can be opened in the browser!

The path does not contain fancy characters. The server is not on Windows, I've read encoding might be a reason for this but don't know what the workaround should be, if that's the case.

Where's could the problem be?

Comment: file permissions ... that's my thought, does php have permission to the file.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: yet php can read the file, enqueue the script via Wordpress... shouldn't it be able to read the file time just as well? Do you know if there is a way to check if it is a permission problem via php?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the real path instead:

```
$myfile = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js';
$realpath = get_template_directory().'/js/script.js';
wp_enqueue_script('mywebsite-script',$myfile , array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( $realpath ), true );
```

Comment: I thought this had failed too, but I was wrong, I had messed up while commenting out parts. This worked. Thanks! Funny how I found examples out there using the `_uri` Wordpress thingy.

Comment: I just found out that this breaks locally on my xampp. The "real path" to the script now looks something like: `http://localhost/folderD:foldersonhardiskwithnospaces/wp-content/themes/theme/js/script.js`...

Comment: get_template_directory() will return a real path such as: 

/var/www/wordpress/wp.local/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen (linux)

I see you provide is an 'uri' not 'directory path'. am I wrong ?

Comment: yes, I needed it for `filemtime` but not for `wp_enqueue_script`. Now I've separated the two, as I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265585/strange-behavior-of-wp-enqueue-script-on-a-local-xampp-install), answering my own question.