# strange behavior of wp_enqueue_script on a local xampp install

Tags: php, wordpress, path, xampp

I want to call a js file with `wp_enqueue_script`.

I use `get_template_directory()`, like so:

```
$myfile = wp_normalize_path(get_template_directory().'/js/script.js');
$myversion = filemtime($myfile);
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', $myfile , array( 'jquery' ), $myversion, true );
```

this works on the server: If I echo `$myfile`, it returns a real path, like `/home/public_html/folder/wp-content/themes/mytwentysixteen/js/script.js`, while on the web page it returns the absolute path to the file correctly.

(Note that the above - at least the `filemtime` part- would fail if I used `get_template_directory_uri`.)

On my local xampp install (Windows machine), this doesn't work.

If I do `echo $myfile`, it returns the correct local path:

```
D:/path/to/folder/wp-content/themes/mytwentysixteen/js/script.js
```

However, following `wp_enqueue_script`, on the web page it returns something like this:

```
http://localhost/folderD:pathtofolder/wp-content/themes/mytwentysixteen/js/script.js
```

and the page fails to retrieve the script.
This seems an odd marriage between the home url on localhost and the local windows path.

`wp_normalize_path` doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the solution is that `get_template_directory()` should not be used to enqueue scripts, but it should be used for php functions like `filemtime`.

Therefore, the solution is to separate the two, like so:

```
$myfile = get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script.js';
$myversion = filemtime(get_template_directory().'/js/script.js');
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', $myfile , array( 'jquery' ), $myversion, true );
```

Here I use `get_template_directory_uri()` to retrieve the script, and `get_template_directory()` to get the timestamp of the file and both work on xampp without a problem.